# Can't add more than 10 rows to my datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I want to add dynamically rows to my DataTable to save them, but when I achieve 10 rows I can't get more than that, and it can't even save it.

```js
// Add row into table
var addRowTable = {
  options: {
    addButton: "#addToTable",
    table: "#addrowExample",
    dialog: {}
  },
  initialize: function() {
    this.setVars().build().events()
  },
  setVars: function() {
    return this.$table = $(this.options.table), this.$addButton = $(this.options.addButton), this.dialog = {}, this.dialog.$wrapper = $(this.options.dialog.wrapper), this.dialog.$cancel = $(this.options.dialog.cancelButton), this.dialog.$confirm = $(this.options.dialog.confirmButton), this
  },
  build: function() {
    //var window.table = this.datatable;
    return this.datatable = this.$table.DataTable({
      aoColumns: [null, null, null, null, null, null, {
        bSortable: !1
      }],
      "sDom": 't'
    }), window.dt = this.datatable, this
  },
  events: function() {
    var object = this;
    return this.$table.on("click", "button.button-save", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(), object.rowSave($(this).closest("tr"))
    }).on("click", "button.button-discard", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(), object.rowCancel($(this).closest("tr"))
    }).on("click", "button.button-remove", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var sumToRemove = $(this).closest('tr').find('td:eq(5)').text();

      //Update sum value
      Application.sumCharge -= parseFloat(sumToRemove);
      $("#lb-sum").html(Application.sumCharge.toFixed(2));

      object.rowRemove($row)

    }), this.$addButton.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(), object.rowAdd()
    }), this.dialog.$cancel.on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(), $.magnificPopup.close()
    }), this
  },
  rowAdd: function() {
    this.$addButton.attr({
      disabled: "disabled"
    });
    var actions, data, $row;
    actions = ['<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing button-save" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Save" hidden><i class="icon-drawer" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>', '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-editing button-discard" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Discard" hidden><i class="icon-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>', '<button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-pure btn-default on-default button-remove"><i class="icon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>'].join(" "), data = this.datatable.row.add(["", "", "", "", "", "", actions]), ($row = this.datatable.row(data[0]).nodes().to$()).addClass("adding").find("td:last").addClass("actions"), this.rowEdit($row), this.datatable.order([0, "asc"]).draw()
  },
  rowCancel: function($row) {
    var $actions, data;
    $row.hasClass("adding") ? this.rowRemove($row) : (($actions = $row.find("td.actions")).find(".button-discard").tooltip("hide"), $actions.get(0) && this.rowSetActionsDefault($row), data = this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(data), this.handleTooltip($row), this.datatable.draw())
  },
  rowEdit: function($row) {
    var counter = 0;
    var data, object = this;
    data = this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(), $row.children("td").each(function(i) {
      var $this = $(this);

      if (counter == 0) {
        Application.tableLength++;
        $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<label style="font-weight: 400 !important">' + Application.tableLength + '</label>');
      } else if (counter > 0 && counter < 5) {

        if (counter == 1) {
          $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" data-provide="datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" class="form-control input-date" value="' + data[i] + '" required>');

        } else if (counter == 2) {
          $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + data[i] + '" required>');

        } else if (counter == 3) {
          $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + data[i] + '" required>');

        } else if (counter == 4) {
          $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + data[i] + '" required>');


        }
      } else {
        $this.hasClass("actions") ? object.rowSetActionsEditing($row) : $this.html('<input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" value="' + data[i] + '" required>');

      }
      counter++;

    })
  },
  rowSave: function($row) {
    if ($('#form').get(0).reportValidity()) {
      var $actions, object = this,
        values = [],
        counter = 0;

      $row.hasClass("adding") && (this.$addButton.removeAttr("disabled"), $row.removeClass("adding")), values = $row.find("td").map(function() {
        var $this = $(this),
          input = '',
          input_value = $this.find("label,input,textarea").val();

        if ($this.hasClass("actions")) {
          return object.rowSetActionsDefault($row), object.datatable.cell(this).data();
        } else {
          if (counter == 0) {
            input = $this.find("label").text();
          } else if (counter > 0 && counter < 5) {
            if (counter == 1) {
              input = "<input type='hidden' name='date[]' value='" + input_value + "'>";

            }
            if (counter == 2) {
              input = "<input type='hidden' name='description[]'  value='" + input_value + "'>";

            } else if (counter == 3) {
              input = "<input type='hidden' name='details[]'  value='" + input_value + "'>";

            } else if (counter == 4) {
              input = "<input type='hidden' name='charge_observation[]'  value='" + input_value + "'>";


            }
          } else {
            input = "<input type='hidden' name='sum[]'  value='" + input_value + "'>";
            Application.sumCharge += parseFloat(input_value);
            $("#lb-sum").html(Application.sumCharge.toFixed(2));
          }
          counter++;

          return $.trim($this.find("label,input,textarea").val()) + input;
        }

      }), ($actions = $row.find("td.actions")).find(".button-save").tooltip("hide"), $actions.get(0) && this.rowSetActionsDefault($row), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).data(values), this.handleTooltip($row), this.datatable.draw()
    }
  },
  rowRemove: function($row) {
    $row.hasClass("adding") && this.$addButton.removeAttr("disabled"), this.datatable.row($row.get(0)).remove().draw()
  },
  rowSetActionsEditing: function($row) {
    $row.find(".on-editing").removeAttr("hidden"), $row.find(".on-default").attr("hidden", !0)
  },
  rowSetActionsDefault: function($row) {
    $row.find(".on-editing").attr("hidden", !0), $row.find(".on-default").removeAttr("hidden")
  },
  handleTooltip: function($row) {
    $row.find('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
  }
};
$(function() {
  addRowTable.initialize()
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped fixed" cellspacing="0" id="addrowExample">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th style="width: 5%">#</th>
        <th>{{ __('all.date')}}</th>
        <th>{{ __('all.description')}}</th>
        <th>{{ __('all.details')}}</th>
        <th style="width: 25%">{{ __('all.observation')}}</th>
        <th>{{ __('all.sum')}}</th>
        <th style="width: 10%">{{ __('all.action')}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>

    <tbody>

    </tbody>
  </table>
  <h6 class="p-10 bg-primary text-light text-right">{{ __('all.total sum')}} : <b id="lb-sum">0.00</b> <small>MAD</small></h6>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code throws error `this.$table.DataTable`. Could you please first fix this (Add minimal working code ==> as snippet not as copy-paste code).

Comment: Worth a read: [mcve] - the idea is to present the *minimal* code to demonstrate your issue (and working enough to demonstrate the issue (so no need for the `Application` logic which is blocking your snippet) - is your issue with *adding* a row?  Then no need for edit/save/etc code that just obfuscates your problem.

Comment: To further support @freedomn-m's point: creating an MCVE requires finding a (reasonable approximation of) the offending code, which is something you should be doing when troubleshooting issues anyway; well before the stage of asking others (not just online). It's easy to forget and sometimes skip ahead to the question asking stage, but reducing the problem to only the code that causes the problem will almost always already give you the answer you seek.